# "boob" look cover on walls in an older home... What are they

Tags: electrical, walls

My brother in law has these "boob" looking covers on his walls. I'm trying to figure out what they are, and then how to remove it. They are pretty caked up with paint.

I was thinking of taking a hammer to them, but that's usually not the best thing to do.

Any idea?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Near the ceiling? floor?. If it is 1900 or older, some areas had pipes for gas lighting;  They could be caps on the pipes. A common location was high in hallways .

Comment: Usually, the "nipple" unscrews. But you may have to crack or chip away the paint.

Comment: Age of house and placement on the walls might narrow it down.  Might just be decoration or old light switches(maybe still with power).  One picture looks like it is high on a wall(above switch height)

Comment: @crip659 Have to agree with Crip. Looks like old light switches to me.

Comment: These are on the wall...about a 3/4 from the floor.

Answer (score 1):

**I think it is a heat detector.**

[image: heat detector]

https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-smoke-heat-detectors-1810835303

This is in the right sort of place for something like this.
A lot of these ancestors of the smoke detector had a "boob" configuration.  I think the nipple equivalent was a low melting point metal and when it melted the alarm would trigger.

Comment: Looks like it. But there are two of them about 6 feet from each other (next to each other). I was thinking they are electrical covers.. but not sure.